# Project not running in spring tool suite

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

I am trying to run a project which is not created here, but imported into this PC.

I switched its database from MySQL to PostgreSQL, and now it's not executing completely. It's stopping here:

```
:: Spring Boot ::       (v1.5.10.RELEASE)

2018-09-14 10:35:34.688  INFO 14924 --- [           main] com.magnus.MagnusItApplication           : Starting MagnusItApplication on CHETNALE22674 with PID 14924 (D:\MagnusIT-master\target\classes started by adarsh.singh in D:\MagnusIT-master)
2018-09-14 10:35:34.688  INFO 14924 --- [           main] com.magnus.MagnusItApplication           : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-09-14 10:35:34.766  INFO 14924 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@3c87521: startup date [Fri Sep 14 10:35:34 IST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-09-14 10:35:35.816  INFO 14924 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d64197d4] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-09-14 10:35:36.146  INFO 14924 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 9090 (http)
2018-09-14 10:35:36.177  INFO 14924 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2018-09-14 10:35:36.177  INFO 14924 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.27
2018-09-14 10:35:36.333  INFO 14924 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2018-09-14 10:35:36.333  INFO 14924 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1567 ms
2018-09-14 10:35:36.474  INFO 14924 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2018-09-14 10:35:36.474  INFO 14924 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2018-09-14 10:35:36.474  INFO 14924 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2018-09-14 10:35:36.474  INFO 14924 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2018-09-14 10:35:36.474  INFO 14924 --- [ost-startStop-1] .s.DelegatingFilterProxyRegistrationBean : Mapping filter: 'springSecurityFilterChain' to: [/*]
2018-09-14 10:35:36.474  INFO 14924 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
```

Here is its application.properties:

```
server.port= 9090

spring.datasource.url= jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=npci@123
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver

#spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/magnus
#spring.datasource.username=root
#spring.datasource.password=root
#spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
#spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

logging.level.root=info
logging.pattern.file=%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36}.%M - %msg%n
logging.level.com.restcrud.emp=debug
logging.path=logs
logging.file=${logging.path}/crudlog.log

spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.port=587
spring.mail.username=team.magnus.it
spring.mail.password=team@magnus
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
```

Comment: paste full stacktrace.

Comment: did you add the credential and corresponding jar ?

Comment: Its coming till here. Its stopping here no going beyond this

Comment: can you explain how did you switched the database..and also add application.properties

Comment: you should print the debug log to see more